# Diplay content in specific DIV or New Window or PopUp Etc, By Custom <A> tag Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to make a system that takes care of many of the required task for supplemental pages, i have was pretty sure this was the right way to do this, but i cant seem to get it to work.

I want to be able to set a custom attribute and have the system set the display type. Main DIV in Main Window, or Main Div in A PopUp window.

```
<a data-target="#MainFrame" href="Page.php" class="Menu">App</a>
```

But the code i'm using keeps creating *PopUps* even though i'm using the *#MainFrame* ID in the  data target.

Any ideas or tips would be appreciated.

```
    <script>
```

$('[data-target]').click( function (e) {

```
var target = $($(this).attr('data-target'));
$('#loaderImage').show();
if (target = "PopUp") 
{   
newPopup($(this).attr('href')); 
$('#loaderImage').hide();
e.preventDefault();
}   
else   
 {
target.load($(this).attr('href'));
$('#loaderImage').hide();
e.preventDefault();
}
 // prevent anchor from changing window.location
```

});

```
  function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
    url,'popUpWindow','height=450,width=400,left=10,top=10,resizable=no,scrollbars=no,toolbar=no,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes');
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `target = "PopUp"` is assigning the value "PopUp" to target, and will always evaluate to "truthy".

Try a double == for comparison, `target == "PopUp"` but I'm not sure it will evaluate correctly still, since it is a jquery object, which does not == a string necessarily.

Try something like this:

```
var target = $(this).attr('data-target');
$('#loaderImage').show();
if (target == "PopUp") 
{   
   newPopup($(this).attr('href')); 
   $('#loaderImage').hide();
   e.preventDefault();
}   
else   
{
   $(target).load($(this).attr('href'));
   $('#loaderImage').hide();
   e.preventDefault();
}
```